# Centering two images but aligning them left

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, errors, boxes

How would I place two images below each other so that their left sides are aligned and the whole construction is centered?

I tried like this:

```
\makebox[120]{}\includegraphics[width=210]{images/img001_1.png}
\\
\makebox[120]{}\includegraphics[width=160]{images/img001_2.png}
```

But that deems me a crude method. LaTeX doesn't like it either:

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \makebox[120]{}
>
> Illegal unit ofmeasure (pt inserted) ...egraphics[width=210]{images/img001_1.png}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \makebox[120]{}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) ...egraphics[width=160]{images/img001_2.png}
>
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) ...egraphics[width=160]{images/img001_2.png}

I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two `\makeboxes` with `l`(eft) alignment and both having a width equal to the width of the widest figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for visualization purposes in the example

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[7cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\makebox[7cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Two images  below each other; their left sides are aligned and the whole construction is centered}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[3cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\makebox[3cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Two images  below each other; their left sides are aligned and the whole construction is centered}
\end{figure}

\noindent  X\dotfill X % just for visualization

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if no flotation is desired, instead of `figure` you can simply use a `center` (or a `minipage` environment with `\centering`) and `\captionof` (from the `caption` package) to provide an eventual caption.

Comment: Good answer. Can also be written shorter with `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`: Then just add e.g. `left=7cm` to the option list: `\includegraphics[width=2cm,left=7cm,center]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=3cm,left=7cm,center]{example-image-b}`. The `center` option replaces the `\centering` and the need for ``\\``.

Answer (score 4):

The `\makebox[<length>]{<content>}` carries a length not just an integer; thus, the error

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \makebox[120]{}
```

Something like `120em` instead of 120 will help. For more information read the following extract I got from [LaTeX Spaces and Boxes](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#makebox). Here is another useful link on the [`\makebox`](http://www-hermes.desy.de/latex/ltx-262.html)command.

> ```
> \makebox[width][position]{text}
> ```
>
> The `\makebox` command creates a box to contain the text specified.
>   The width of the box is specified by the optional width argument. The
>   position of the text within the box is determined by the optional
>   position argument described below:
>
> - `c` - centered (default)
> - `l` - flushleft
> - `r` - flushright
> - `s` - spread

Answer (score 2):

Azetina's answer tells you the exact syntax. This answer tries to provide an illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}  %% showframe just for demo
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  %% syntax \makebox[<width with units>][<position - l/c/r/s>]{<content>}
  \makebox[4cm][r]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
  \makebox[4cm][c]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}}
  \end{center}      

  \begin{center}
  \makebox[4cm][l]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
  \makebox[4cm][c]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}}
  \end{center}

  \noindent 
  X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `s`

Comment: `\noindent` is not needed inside `center` (nor before it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Uh. Remnants of previous code. Thanks.